# Is it possible to tick "add cherry picked from" by default?

Tags: tortoise-git

When I do a cherry pick with TortoiseGit, I always tick the *add "cherry picked from"* checkbox. Is there any way to tick it by default?

Answer (score 1):

As of TortoiseGit 2.12 there is no way to remember/autoselect this option.